# I can't run my app on emulator and found error on logcats

Tags: android, colors, runtimeexception

i want to run my app on the emulator but then i can't open and it says Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped
and i searched the google and i was told to look at logcat and found this

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: A TaskDescription's primary color should be opaque
                  at android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription.<init>(ActivityManager.java:586)
                  at android.app.Activity.onApplyThemeResource(Activity.java:3731)
                  at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:150)
                  at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.setTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:94)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setTheme(AppCompatActivity.java:90)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

and here is my colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<color name="colorPrimary">#bb000000</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#d79d9f9f</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
<color name="colorMerah">#d79d9f9f</color>
<color name="a">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="buttonColor">#bb000000</color>

</resources>
```

your help would mean so much to me please help me, this is my first app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use color values like xx0xxxxxx like that, colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark in your case. Try using a solid six digit hex color, just like colorAccent in there

Comment: THANK YOU SOO MUCHH IT WORKS